# Bootstrap toggle navbar not showing content

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am a newbie to bootstrap, I am having problem with my toggle navBar menu. the data or the list item just do not appear when the screen size is reduced to mobile size there appears the toggle button but it just not do anything.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other         head content must come *after* these tags -->
      <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

      <!-- Bootstrap -->
      <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

      <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and     media queries -->
      <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
      <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"> </script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
      <![endif]-->

      </head>
      <body>
         <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
           <div class="container">
             <div class="navbar-header">
               <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data- toggle="collapse" data-target="navbar-container">
               <span class="sr-only">Show & hide the Navigation</span>
               </button>
             </div>
             <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-container">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
             </div>

         </div>    
      </div>

       <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
       <script    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js">        </script>
         <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files   as needed -->
      <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      </body>
      </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there are 2 mistakes in your code.

Replace this  line

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data- toggle="collapse" data-target="navbar-container">
```

with that one

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-container">
```

**Reason**

There was a space in between data-toggle and you had not put **#** sign with navbar-container in data-target attribute.